# How can I remove the last comma separator from the end of a file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

How can remove the last comma separator from a file on Linux?

Example of file :

```
"is_supported_kafka_ranger" : "true",
"kafka_log_dir" : "/var/log/kafka",
"kafka_pid_dir" : "/var/run/kafka",
"kafka_user" : "kafka",
"kafka_user_nofile_limit" : "128000",
"kafka_user_nproc_limit" : "65536",
```

expected results:

```
"is_supported_kafka_ranger" : "true",
"kafka_log_dir" : "/var/log/kafka",
"kafka_pid_dir" : "/var/run/kafka",
"kafka_user" : "kafka",
"kafka_user_nofile_limit" : "128000",
"kafka_user_nproc_limit" : "65536"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305177/how-can-i-remove-the-last-character-of-a-file-in-unix

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
sed -i '$s/,$//' file
```

That is, on the last line (`$`) substitute (`s`) the comma at the end of the line (`,$`) by nothing.

The change will be done in-place due to the `-i` flag.

With standard `sed`:

```
sed '$s/,$//' <file >file.new &&
mv file.new file
```

---

Note: Someone suggested an edit to change "on the last line" to "last on the line" (or something similar). This is wrong. When `$` is used to specify an address (a line where to apply an editing command), then it refers to the last line of the stream or file. This is *different* from using `$` in a regular expression.

Answer (score 6):

For in-place editing you could use `ed` - conveniently, it sets the position to the last line by default on opening so you don't need to address the last line explicitly:

```
ed file
s/,$//
wq
```

Or, as a one-liner

```
printf 's/,$//\nwq\n' | ed -s file
```

Comment: In bash you can dispense with `printf` like this: `ed -s file <<< $'s/,$//\nwq\n'` (the keyword for search in the bash manual is "here string").

Answer (score 5):

In general, I'd probably go with the straightforward `sed` solution.  However, if your input files are huge, you might want a solution that doesn't take the time to read through the whole file just to edit the last couple of bytes.

If you are 100% sure your input file ends with a comma followed by a newline, you can use [`truncate`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/truncate-invocation.html#truncate-invocation) to lop off these last two characters, and then re-append a final newline:

```bash
filesize=$(stat -L --format "%s" lastcomma.txt)
truncate --size $((filesize - 2)) lastcomma.txt 
echo >> lastcomma.txt
```

This assumes a distro that includes GNU truncate or equivalent.

---

@StéphaneChazelas points out that *GNU `truncate` now supports `truncate -s -2 file` to shorten the file by two bytes*; if you have this version, the above simplifies to:

```bash
truncate --size -2 lastcomma.txt
echo >> lastcomma.txt
```

Comment: ...and a filesystem that supports `truncate`

Comment: @malat, what file system doesn't support truncate?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Right this is poorly worded. How about: [...] and a filesystem that supports sparse file to have an efficient `truncate`. The OP describe his solution starting with: " if your input files are huge"... hence my comment.

Comment: GNU `truncate` now supports `truncate -s -2 file` to shorten the file by two bytes. You'd want to use `stat -L` as for symlinks, you  want the size of the target of the symlink (or simply `size=$(wc -c < file)`).

Comment: @malat, you  don't need sparse file support to truncate files. Here, we're trimming data off the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneChazelas.  I was assuming `wc` always ends up reading the whole file, but looking at [the source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/wc.c;h=0c72042a0b28092ad4660671a7075ba299996dc5;hb=HEAD#l239), it appears to be smart enough just to `lseek()` if it is only counting bytes.  `strace` confirms this.